# While connecting to a MySql database with PHP, is it a bad idea to modify the db config based on user input?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Sorry if the title is not clear, I'm in a project where we're building an Android app that connects to a MySql database to display some data. We're using PHP to connect to the database, and we're using dbconfig.php that contains something along the lines of:

```
define("servername", "host");
define("username", "username");
define("password", "password");
define("database",  "database");
```

Since we are often connecting to databases hosted in different servers, we had to manually change the dbconfig every time before running the app, so we're thinking of letting the user write this information on the app itself. I thought of making the app send a POST request then having the dbconfig have something like this:

```
define("servername", $_POST["host"]);
define("username", $_POST["username"]);
define("password", $_POST["password"]);
define("database",  $_POST["database"]);
```

But I know the dbconfig is supposed to be secure so I am not comfortable dynamically changing the dbconfig and looks like a bad idea.  What is the best way of achieving this?

Edit: It is a bad idea, on another note how would an app similar to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kriskast.remotedb) work? 
Would it not require some type of POST request to send the database credentials onto a server side language?

Comment: Oh, that's a very bad idea, since it can be used for hijacking. I'd suggest keeping a static config, and switch the variables based on user selection. Have a list of systems, like "System 1", "System 2", "Books", "Music", or whatever you need, and switch the credentials based on that value.

Comment: Whats the app do to need to change db hosts dynamically? Is it a database admin system? If not then them values should be hardcoded in the config or set as environment variables through the deployment process.

Comment: Yes I figured it's a bad idea I was just wondering if there are any alternatives. They got this idea from heidi or any sql tool where you add the host user pass etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a real bad idea, because:

- you are passing credentials via POST
- you do not sanitize/strip the credentials (the $_POST content)
- you are transferring your credentials via HTTP(S) (or something else)

One approach is to define some REST endpoints and let your app call those endpoints. The endpoints can then decide to which server they are going to connect.

Comment: Yes it's a bad idea I just wasn't sure if there was a way to do it securely. The REST endpoints is a good idea but they were thinking of a way where the user can add and remove the database settings from the app itself, so there is no "real" fixed number  of endpoints. I'll just stick to writing the config statically

Answer (score 0):

if you are in development mode you could have a different home page to send the name of the database to use .. something similar to this

```
$db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : 'default';

switch ($db) {
    case 'db1':
        $servername = 'host1';
        $username   = 'username1';
        $password   = 'password1';
        $database   = 'database1';
        break;
    case 'db2':
        $servername = 'host2';
        $username   = 'username2';
        $password   = 'password2';
        $database   = 'database2';
        break;
    default:
        $servername = 'default_host';
        $username   = 'default_username';
        $password   = 'default_password';
        $database   = 'default_database';
        break;
}

define("SERVERNAME", $servername);
define("USERNAME",   $username);
define("PASSWORD",   $password);
define("DATABASE",   $database);
```