# Wouldn't a MySQL app on Android always be insecure?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560743/while-connecting-to-a-mysql-database-with-php-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-modify-the-db) today about dynamically changing a php config file for connecting to MySQL, and it was obvious it's a bad idea. But after searching the Play Store I found a [MySQL client app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kriskast.remotedb) where you can add connections after inputting the host,database, username and password, which makes me wonder how that app works. Does it not send a POST request with the database information to create a config file with whatever server side language they're using? If it does that then does that mean the app is not very secure? Or is it using another way to connect to the database?

Comment: *"I asked a question today"* - which is still considered as being unsolved/open.

Comment: But I have another question, I was just using that one as context.

Comment: The only people who can tell you exactly how a specific app works internally are those who built it.

Comment: Do you have dbconfig hardcoded in your app? Why don't you make a service to update the config securely?

Comment: So you're building a mysql client, adminer, phpmyadmin for android? If your not then what is the app do? If its a shoe store app, maybe its not a good idea to give your users credentials to the database.

Comment: obviously insecure, because connection data is visible on android, and if somebodyy see that connection they easily can connect to it